# The CSR matrix representation in Tensorflow

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, matrix, sparse-matrix

My tutor wants me to implement the function `tf.raw_ops.SparseMatrixTranspose`

So I came to the website https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/SparseMatrixTranspose to do some research on it. And at the website, it said this function is used to transpose a `CSR sparse matrix`.

So I went here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sparse-matrix-representations-set-3-csr/ to get some more information about it, and it told me that the CSR representation of a matrix is three arrays called `A, IA, JA`.

So I went to `tensorflow.org` to find some function that can generate a CSR representation of a matrix, and I found this function https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/raw_ops/DenseToCSRSparseMatrix.

So I used the script below to test this function

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
# dense_input=np.array([[[1,2,0]],[[1,2,0]],[[1,2,0]]]).astype(np.float32)
dense_input=np.array([[1,2,0], [1,2,0],[1,2,0]]).astype(np.float32)
print("dense=",dense_input)
# csr=tf.raw_ops.DenseToCSRSparseMatrix(
#     dense_input=dense_input, indices=[[0, 0, 0],[0,0,1], [1,0,1],[1,0,1]], name=None
# )

csr=tf.raw_ops.DenseToCSRSparseMatrix(
    dense_input=dense_input, indices=[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],[2,0],[2,1]], name=None
)

tt=tf.raw_ops.SparseMatrixTranspose(
    input=csr, type=tf.float32, conjugate=False, name=None
)

tf.print(csr)
tf.print(tt)
```

But the output is quite confused to me because the output CSR representation is not the three arrays
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNCYt.png]
Is the CSR representation in TensorFlow different from what I learned?  please help me.

[colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/160cmnJKbQFxzG2IPhYGCysPoaCCf7eQT?usp=sharing)

[This is my basic CSR format transpose](https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y22ae4dae)
[image: works like this]

Comment: You could 'cheat' and look at how `scipy.sparse` does the transpose.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your reply, I already have checked out CSR sparse in SciPy, and implemented a basic CSR format transpose in C++ (It takes a CSR format of a matrix and outputs the CSR format of the transpose version of the matrix, and has the time complexity **O(cols + nnz)**), but what I am supposed to do is implement the exact same API as Tensorflow, so I really need to figure out how the CSR format works in Tensorflow

Answer (score 0):

I'm familiar with the `scipy.sparse` code, not tensorflow, though I imagine it's following the same basic practices.  Formats like `csr` and `csc` are well known.

I'll illustrate what I throught `scipy` would add to your thinking.

```
In [36]: from scipy import sparse
```

Your original matrix:

```
In [37]: A = np.array([10,20,30,4,50,60,70,80])    
In [38]: IA = np.array([0,2,4,7,8])    
In [39]: JA = np.array([0,1,1,3,2,3,4,5])
In [41]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((A,JA,IA))
In [42]: M
Out[42]: 
<4x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The `repr` display of a sparse matrix identifies its format, dtype, shape and number of nonzero elements.  There is a `str` display that lists all nonzero terms with their coordinates.

```
In [43]: M.A     # todense
Out[43]: 
array([[10, 20,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 30,  0,  4,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 50, 60, 70,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 80]])
```

The transpose of a csr is a csc, with the same attributes - more on that later.  This is a trivial transformation, almost as trivial as `numpy` transpose which is a `view` with different strides.

```
In [44]: MT = M.T
In [45]: MT
Out[45]: 
<6x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>    
In [46]: MT.A
Out[46]: 
array([[10,  0,  0,  0],
       [20, 30,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 50,  0],
       [ 0,  4, 60,  0],
       [ 0,  0, 70,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, 80]])
```

The csc can be converted to  a csr.  This is a more complicated operation.  But it isn't unique to the transpose.

```
In [47]: MTR = MT.tocsr()
```

To see the underlying arrays we have to look at them individually.

```
In [49]: M.data, M.indices, M.indptr
Out[49]: 
(array([10, 20, 30,  4, 50, 60, 70, 80]),
 array([0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 2, 4, 7, 8]))

In [50]: MT.data, MT.indices, MT.indptr      # same 3 arrays
Out[50]: 
(array([10, 20, 30,  4, 50, 60, 70, 80]),
 array([0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 2, 4, 7, 8]))

In [51]: MTR.data, MTR.indices, MTR.indptr     # same ones you show
Out[51]: 
(array([10, 20, 30, 50,  4, 60, 70, 80], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32))
```

Looking at `MT.tocsr??` (in Ipython) I see most of the work is in a `csc_tocsr` function.  But `csc_tocsr` is  a "builtin", i.e. a compiled function, probably written in `cython`.